# Why is geothermal heat insignificant to surface temperature?

Tags: climate, temperature, geothermal-heat

I believe the temperature gradient underground is as high as 30°C per kilometer of depth. Thus, it is very warm only 1 kilometer below the Earth's surface. Yet, it is commonly stated that geothermal energy is insignificant to the Earth's surface temperature. How can this be?

Comment: 1km of rock is a damn good insulator. Very little energy reaches the surface.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One kilometer of rock is actually a lot to dig through to get to that very warm condition.

The key quantity here is **heat flux.** The crux of the matter is:

Geothermal heat flux is only a small fraction of a percent of solar heat flux.

Solar heat flux balance terms are on the order of tens to hundreds of watts per square meter [source](https://www.azimuthproject.org/azimuth/show/Solar+radiation):

> The earth’s surface absorbs 156 W/m² from the sun (as a global average) and emits 55 W/m² long-wave energy to the atmosphere. The atmosphere absorbs 84 W/m² and emits 185 W/m² as longwave radiation to space.
>
> The above figures are from Barry and Chorley, 2003[¹]. The account in Kiehl and Trenberth’s 1997 paper[²] is more complicated, but it can be partially summarized by this picture:
>
> In particular, note that they list:
>
> 342 W/m² (341 W/m²) average power hitting the Earth’s atmosphere.
>
> 198 W/m² (184 W/m²) average power hitting the Earth’s surface.
>
> 168 W/m² (161 W/m²) average power being absorbed by the Earth’s surface.
>
> Bracketed figures are from the Trenberth et al 2009 paper[³].

In contrast, geothermal heat flux is measured in tens of *milliwatts* per square meter:

> Heat flows constantly from its sources within Earth to the surface. Total heat loss from Earth is estimated at 44.2 TW (4.42 × 10¹³ watts).[⁴] Mean heat flow is 65 mW/m² over continental crust and 101 mW/m² over oceanic crust.[⁴] This is 0.087 watt/square metre on average (0.03 percent of solar power absorbed by Earth[⁵]), but is much more concentrated in areas where the lithosphere is thin, such as along mid-ocean ridges (where new oceanic lithosphere is created) and near mantle plumes.[⁶]

**Cited References**

1. R. G. Barry and R. J. Chorley (2003), *Atmosphere, Weather and Climate*, Routledge, London, 2003.
2. J. T. Kiehl and Kevin E. Trenberth (1997), "Earth’s annual global mean energy budget", *Bull. Amer. Meteor. Soc.* **78**, 197–208.
3. K. E. Trenberth, J. T. Fasullo, and J. Kiehl (2009), "Earth’s global energy budget", *Bull. Amer. Meteor. Soc.* **90**, 311–323.
4. Pollack, Henry N., et.al. (1993) "Heat flow from Earth's interior: Analysis of the global data set", *Reviews of Geophysics*, **31**, 3, p. 273. Archived 2011-08-11 at the Wayback Machine. [doi:10.1029/93RG01249](https://doi.org/10.1029/93RG01249)
5. "Climate and Earth's Energy Budget". NASA. 2009-01-14.
6. Richards, M. A.; Duncan, R. A.; Courtillot, V. E. (1989). "Flood Basalts and Hot-Spot Tracks: Plume Heads and Tails". *Science* **246** (4926): 103–107. Bibcode:1989Sci...246..103R. [doi:10.1126/science.246.4926.103](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.246.4926.103). PMID 17837768. S2CID 9147772.